# calculate the Euclidean distance between an array in c# with function

Tags: c#, distance

I want to calculate a  euclidean   distance  between points that the user enter,so as you can see here :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int numtest = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    int[,] points=new int[10,2];
    for (int i = 0; i < numtest; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("point " +(i+1).ToString()+" x: ");
        points[i, 0] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("point " + (i + 1).ToString() + " y: ");
        points[i, 1] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    }
}

public float[] calculate(int[,] points)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <points.Length ; i++)
    {

    }
}
```

[image]

is there any function in c# that can do this ?

I need to have each distance value between all points in my array

Comment: Yes, C# has multiplication and `Math.Sqrt`, which can be combined to calculate this

Comment: @luqui i mean a function that get an array and calculate the distance between all points

Comment: IOW: make a `float` variable, and as you loop through the two arrays, add the square of the difference between the two elements to the variable. Then after the loop, take the square root of the variable.

Comment: C# does not have a built in function to do this, you have to write it yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try following

```
public void calculate(double[,] points)
{
    var distanceArray = new double[points.Length, points.Length];

    for (int i = 0; i < points.Length; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < points.Length; j++)
            distanceArray[i, j] = Distance(points[i, 0], points[i, 1], points[j, 0], points[j, 1]);
}

public static double Distance(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2)
=>  Math.Sqrt(((x1 - x2) * (x1 - x2) + (y1 - y2) * (y1 - y2)));
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is how to implement the distance calculation between two given points, to get you started:

```
int x0 = 0;
int y0 = 0;

int x1 = 100;
int y1 = 100;

int dX = x1 - x0;
int dY = y1 - y0;
double distance = Math.Sqrt(dX * dX + dY * dY);
```